# Adding Items at MenuStrip Combobox

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a Menu Strip which contains a ComboBox. How do I put items in my ComboBox during the design stage, NOT at runtime? I changed the property AutoCompleteSource = CustomSource and I put items inside AutoCompleteCustomSource and still, no luck. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the menu bar item and go to
"Properties"
and 
"Items"/(Collection)

Hope this helps

Comment: Didn't saw that property earlier. My eyes are playing tricks on me. Thanks. XD

Comment: If you're around the computer hammering those keys and programming ESPECIALLY for a long period it'll happen. All the best